# Rdd verify Date format and remove row if date format is incorrect Scala Spark

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark, rdd

Sample rddDate: [2016-08-01,"pm",5,"ri"]
There are some rows with incorrect format of a date in this RDD, so I can't count rows in RDD. That throws IndexOutOfBound exception.
Used Date format is java.sql.Date

The expected Date Format is for every row in RDD: "yyyy-mm-dd"

```
2016-08-01
```

To verify date format in RDD, below code is implemented,

```
val rddVerified: RDD[(Date, String, Long, String)] = rddDate.map{
                a => {
                    val fmt = DateTimeFormat forPattern "yyyy-mm-dd"
                    val input = a._1.toString
                    try {
                        val output = fmt parseDateTime input
                    } catch {
                        case e: Exception => {
                            val v1 = new java.util.Date("2016-08-01")
                            val v2 = new Date(a1.getTime)
                            val ed:(Date,String, Int, String) = (v2, "p1",2,"r1")
                            Some(ed) // This gives compile time error
                        }
                    } finally {
                        Some(a._1, a._2,a._3,a._4)
                    }

                }
            }
```

I am not able to handle the exception in catch section. I want to either remove that row from the RDD or correct the format of date in that row. 
I want to get returned RDD in this format:

```
RDD[(Date, String, Long, String)]
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Exception when counting Dataframe:

```
COUNT : : 
[error] o.a.s.e.Executor - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 7)
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.apply(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:65)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.apply(List.scala:84)
    at controllers.Spark$$anonfun$5.apply(Spark.scala:78)
    at controllers.Spark$$anonfun$5.apply(Spark.scala:78)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:464)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
[warn] o.a.s.s.TaskSetManager - Lost task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 7, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.apply(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:65)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.apply(List.scala:84)
    at controllers.Spark$$anonfun$5.apply(Spark.scala:78)
    at controllers.Spark$$anonfun$5.apply(Spark.scala:78)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:464)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

[error] o.a.s.s.TaskSetManager - Task 0 in stage 7.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
[warn] o.a.s.s.BlockManager - Putting block rdd_1_1 failed due to an exception
[warn] o.a.s.s.BlockManager - Block rdd_1_1 could not be removed as it was not found on disk or in memory
[warn] o.a.s.s.BlockManager - Putting block rdd_1_2 failed due to an exception
[warn] o.a.s.s.BlockManager - Block rdd_1_2 could not be removed as it was not found on disk or in memory
[warn] o.a.s.s.TaskSetManager - Lost task 1.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 8, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (unknown reason)
[warn] o.a.s.s.TaskSetManager - Lost task 2.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 9, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (unknown reason)
[error] application - 

 stage failure: Task 0 in stage 7.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 7, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.apply(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:65)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.apply(List.scala:84)
    at controllers.Spark$$anonfun$5.apply(Spark.scala:78)
    at controllers.Spark$$anonfun$5.apply(Spark.scala:78)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:464)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:293)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:220)
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
    at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)
    at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:100)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:99)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:346)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:345)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:36)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 7.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 7, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.apply(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:65)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.apply(List.scala:84)
    at controllers.Spark$$anonfun$5.apply(Spark.scala:78)
    at controllers.Spark$$anonfun$5.apply(Spark.scala:78)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:464)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.apply(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:65)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.apply(List.scala:84)
    at controllers.Spark$$anonfun$5.apply(Spark.scala:78)
    at controllers.Spark$$anonfun$5.apply(Spark.scala:78)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:464)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `Dataset`. It is not only faster and simpler, but also future friendly

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.to_date
val spark: SparkSession = ???
import spark.implicits._

rddDate.toDF.withColumn("_1", to_date($"_1"))
  .na.drop(Seq("_1))
  .as[(java.sql.Date, String, Long, String)]
```

**Edit**

But the problem is some else in your code.

> Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Suggest that you make some mistake, probably in the parsing logic. You have to step back to the place where you call `apply` add exception handling there.

Comment: Thanks!!
This is an easier technique to convert to Dataframe from RDD. But it does not check the format of the date. So when I apply `df.count()` it throws an exception. To overcome this problem I wanted to verify date format.

Comment: It does. `sql.functions` are in  general safe. If there is incorrect format you get SQL `NULL`, which is removed in the `na.drop` part. If you get an exception, it is not here. Could you post traceback?

Comment: Updated a question. Added error stacktrace.
`df.printSchema()` `df.show(10)` works, But `df.count()` throws exception

Comment: Oh, `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` doesn't happen here :)